# Doodle Jump game over animation

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Please excuse the stupid question, but I'm working on a game because I'm crazy like that and I really need some help.  When you fall below the screen in doodle jump the game is over and it cuts to end of game animation.  This animation gives the feel of the screen scrolling and him falling -- some how they animate him to the top -- from the top to his death.  Do anybody know who to simulate this animation?  BTW, I'm using Cocos2d for the game engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the answer my self by using this tool called [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/download?f=ipa).  Check it out it very good.